# Change WebGLRenderer.shadowMapType

Tags: three.js

I'm writing tutorial programs for Computer-Graphic lectures in University. For one of them I want to show different kinds of Shadow-mapping. If I change the value of WebGLRenderer.shadowMapType nothing happens onScreen. Is it possible to change the mapping at runtime anyway and how?

Initialize:

```
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias:true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.BasicShadowMap;
```

Update:

```
    renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

Answer (score 3):

To change the `shadowMapType` after the first render, you need to set

```
material.needsUpdate = true;
```

for the material receiving the shadow.

See the Wiki: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

three.js r.54